# Apache POI migration

Tags: apache-poi

I am migrating the code which is using Apache POI-2.5 to POI-5.
I am unable to find the import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.Region; Could please help me where can I find the jar or replacement ?

I need to update below Region with latest implementation from POI-5.
sheet.addMergedRegion(new Region(0,(short)13,0,(short)16));

Thanks!

Comment: [Apache POI 2.5 was released in 2004](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-pre3x.html), [Apache POI 5.0 in 2021](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#5.0.0), you have to expect at least some API changes in 17 years!

Answer (score 0):

sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0,(short)13,0,(short)16));

Comment: https://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/apache-POI/org/apache/poi/hssf/util/Region.html -- has the deprecation notice and details about switching to CellRangeAddress